# Does satellite radio use AM or FM or both?

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation, satellite

Somehow, I cannot find an answer anywhere...  I am guessing both...

Several actual satellites had FM in their names, so perhaps that is a clue, but I want to know for sure...

Comment: Did you wiki this? All I had to do was wiki and look at the Sirius Satellite Radio entry which says "*The satellite signal is QPSK*" which is neither AM nor FM. Rather, it is a type of phase modulation, or PM, if you will.

Comment: Satellite radio is a digital broadcasting. AM/FM is analog one. It is not using AM or FM.

Comment: Voting to close. This is freely available information, this site is not an encyclopaedia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither. Satellite radio such as Sirius transmits the digital data with COFDM-DQPSK modulation.